# Docker node development environment on windows

Tags: node.js, docker, boot2docker, dockerfile

I'm developing a simple NodeJS application. I use docker and it makes it very easy to deploy to production. 
This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node
COPY . /src
RUN cd /src; npm install
EXPOSE  3000
CMD ["node", "/src/express.js"]
```

On my development environment (windows, boot2Docker) Docker is slowing me down, because for every small change I do, I have to re-build the Docker image and run the container and it takes a few minutes.
I couldn't find a way to simply copy my source files from the host to the docker container. Is there an easy way to do it? Should I use plain nodeJS on my development environment and only use Docker in production?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
FROM node
COPY ./package.json /src
RUN cd /src && npm install
COPY . src/
EXPOSE  3000
CMD ["node", "/src/express.js"]
```

The way you originally have it will install npm packages everytime you change something within `src`. If we separate this step, these packages will only be installed if the `package.json` file changes.

Answer (score 1):

At least during development, you could share a folder from your windows OS with docker - would make the code-debug cycle a lot quicker.

Mount a Host Directory as a Data Volume:
https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

(about 1/2 way down the page)